# I could not pass a variable to function from outside of the functiion ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I have created a function component in ReactJS.Also I have a variable outside of the function.It store my question.I want to pass this question to function as a paramether.Here is my code

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';


const questions = [
    {"Question":"This is the first question","Answer":"This is the first Answer"},
    {"Question":"This is the second question","Answer":"This is the second Answer"},
    {"Question":"This is the third question","Answer":"This is the third Answer"},
    {"Question":"This is the forth question","Answer":"This is the forth Answer"},
    {"Question":"This is the fifth question","Answer":"This is the fifth Answer"},
];
function QuizNavBar({questions}) {
  const [questionIndex, setQuestionIndex] = useState(0);

  // define event handlers 
 const goBack = () =>
    setQuestionIndex((prevQuestionIndex) => prevQuestionIndex - 1);
  // determine if on the first question or not 
const goToNext = () =>
    setQuestionIndex((prevQuestionIndex) => prevQuestionIndex + 1);
    
  const onLastQuestion = questionIndex === questions.length - 1;
  const onFirstQuestion=questionIndex===0

  return (
    <nav>
      <span>Question #{questionIndex + 1}</span>
      <div>
        <button onClick={goBack} disabled={onFirstQuestion}
 >
          Go Back
        </button>
        <button disabled={onLastQuestion} onClick={goToNext}>
          Next Question
        </button>
      </div>
    </nav>
  );
}


export default QuizNavBar;
```

Comment: If the `questions` are global, why would you need to pass them anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

your assumption is wrong, props of a function component are for passing data like this:

```
function QuizNavBar({questions}) {...}
...
<QuizNavBar questions={x} />
...
```

in your case if its static you need to just remove questions from function props, and use questions in your function.
but better case would be use it inside of component with "useMemo" like below:

```
const questions = useMemo(()=>[...]);
```

it help in rerenders this variable not be defined again

Comment: Both two ways are working.I passed the question like that   <QuizNavBar questions={questions}/>